# Residue of a generic complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Suppose we have two functions, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, with simple poles at z=0, and that they have residues $1$ and $-2$ at that point. Imagine I want to know how to find the residue of the function:
\begin{equation}
h(z)=f(z)g(z)
\end{equation}
At $z=0$. Let we define the functions $F(z)=zf(z)$ and $G(z)=zg(z)$, s.t it's derivates are $F'(0)=-1$ and $G'(0)=4$, which implies:
\begin{align} 
&f(z)+zf'(z)=-1\\
&g(z)+zg'(z)=4
\end{align}
How could I use these relations in order to calculate the residue of $h(z)$ at $z=0$?

Comment: Are those values for $F'(0)$ and $G'(0)$ given in the problem or something you are deducing?

Comment: Conditions given by the problem. Should've wrote that first.

Comment: If they are given, then you know that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+(-1)+za(z)$ and $g(z)=\frac{-2}{z}+4+zb(z)$, where $a,b$ are holomorphic at $0$. You can multiply $f(z)g(z)$ and get the coefficient of the term with $z^{-1}$, which is $\frac{1}{z}\cdot 4+(-1)\cdot \frac{-2}{z}=\frac{6}{z}$.